# What's the event space of a single coin toss?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Take a probability triple, $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$, representing a single coin toss.

Then
\begin{align}
& \Omega = \{H,T\}. \tag{Prop. 1} \\
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}
\text{A } \sigma \text{-algebra must be closed under countable union}, \tag{Prop. 2}
\end{align}

so
\begin{align}
\text{if we have } \{H\},\{T\} \in \mathscr{F} \text{ then we must also have } \{H,T\} \in \mathscr{F}, \tag{Prop. 3}
\end{align}

but
\begin{align}
\{H,T\} \text{ is not a possible event resulting from a single coin toss.} \tag{Prop. 4}
\end{align}

What's gone wrong?

Comment: You are mixing up _events_ (_collections_ of outcomes} and outcomes. $\{H,T\}=\Omega$ _is_ an event since it is the set containing two outcomes, but it is not, by itself, an outcome. $H$ and $T$ are outcomes, $\{H\}$ and $\{T\}$ are the corresponding _events_ consisting of single outcomes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The event $\{H,T\}$ is that the result of the flip is either $H$ or $T$; this has probability $1$

The event $\emptyset = \{\,\}$ is that  the result of the flip is neither $H$ nor $T$; this has probability $0$

So there is no problem; $\mathscr{F}= \{\emptyset,\{H\},\{T\},\{H,T\}\}$ as you might expect

Comment: So proposition 4 is wrong. I guess that $\{H,T\}$ got interpreted as 'tails *after* heads' instead of 'tails *or* heads'. In that case it resembles an [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) fallacy.